# cannot select option from select box

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Cannot select an item in a select box using selenium 2 firefox (or chrome) driver

```
<select id="activations_month" name="activations[month]">
<option value="April 2011">April 2011</option>
<option value="May 2011">May 2011</option>
<option value="June 2011">June 2011</option>
<option value="July 2011">July 2011</option>
<option value="August 2011">August 2011</option>
<option selected="selected" value="September 2011">September 2011</option>
</select>
```

Select dropDown = new Select(sDriver.findElement(By.id("activations_month"))); 
dropDown.selectByValue("August 2011");

I have tried select by value, by index, by visible text and deselecting and all just fail to do anything.  My try catch does not catch an exception it exits back out into the testNG test runner and onto the next method

This does work fine and returns the correct values

```
List<WebElement> options = dropDown.getOptions(); 

System.out.println(options.size());
System.out.println(options.get(0).getText());
System.out.println(options.get(1).getText());
```

Comment: more info:  Actually stepping into the selenium select code itself it fails to find my search string in the xpath check that it does as soon as you enter the selectByVisibleText method then it seems to just bounce out of the select code with a InvocationTargetException and testNG takes over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work around your problem, whatever it is.  Not the greatest way to select an option but it should work:

```
List<WebElement> options = dropDown.getOptions();
for(WebElement option : options)
{
    if( option.getAttribute("value").equals("August 2011") )
    {
        option.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: that does indeed work.  I find it odd that I have to do that as selenium seems to natively want to let you select with less code.  anyways thank you if anyone knows why my original code fails let me know

Comment: Hey ducati, normally the way you tried does work.  There is probably some quirk with the page you are working with.  I have seen page specific cases where selectbyvalue was failing because the element wasn't "visible" according to selenium even though it was visible in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the ideal solution, but in the interest of keeping this simple (and to get it to work), have you tried instantiating a `WebDriverBackedSelenium`?

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "your_url");
```

Followed by the conventional -

```
selenium.select("id=activations_month", "label=May 2011");
selenium.select("id=activations_month", "label=June 2011");
```

Comment: Problem with that is I have already navigated to the page and done several steps before.  So I would need to write this whole test with selenium backed web driver.  Not ideal.  If it helps I think this is an actual selenium bug.  this worked a while back as well this is code I wrote that was working I want to say it broke with a firefox update but I have also updated selenium modules.

Comment: f I try to select by index I drop into this code in selenium select

    boolean matched = false;
    for (WebElement option : getOptions()) {
      if (match.equals(option.getAttribute("index"))) {
        option.setSelected();
        if (!isMultiple()) {  return;  }
        matched = true;
      }

I asked for index 3 in my code like so -> dropDown.selectByIndex(3);

I see it step through and on index it matches goes to option.setSelected(); and fails out to a
invocationTargetException which is not handled in the method so I am done in the select and back out to the test runner.  Thoughts?

Comment: This article gives the equivalent of Selenium RC commands - 
http://rostislav-matl.blogspot.com/2011/03/moving-to-selenium-2-on-webdriver-part_26.html

Comment: Thank you but those are the commands I am using they just dont seem to work.